# Xcode Search Navigator _really_ slow, but only in a particular project

Tags: xcode, search

One of my projects seems to be nearly impossible to search through in Xcode 4.3.2 on Lion lately. Using the search navigator to find anything in my project basically locks up my whole computer, with the beach ball, for 30 seconds or more.

I've tried deleting the project.xcworkspace file (which is very small anyway), and that didn't fix it. I've tried clicking on the Xcode activity viewer, but everything is locked up, so I can't see anything helpful.

With the Activity Monitor application, I can see the CPU spike when the search starts, and then it comes down to normal, and then Xcode hangs (appears as Not Responding) until it finally times out or something.

Other projects are fine. Search proceeds normally. And this only started in the last few weeks.

What I'm really worried about is a hard drive problem, but this seems very localized, and Disk Utility thinks my drive is fine.

I guess I can try making a copy of my project and searching the copy.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?!

[Screenshot: Find gets stuck...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFUZu.png)

Comment: try deleting and rebuilding the code sense index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuilding the code sense index didn't work either.

I did solve the problem though. The problem was a single file in my project - it seemed to be corrupt or damaged in some way. It couldn't be copied (which is how I discovered the culprit). It also couldn't be 'quick looked' or examined.

All I had to do was delete the damaged file, and revert it from my source control. And problem solved.

Now, how did it get damaged? I have no idea.